# Angular app show different UI between local & production environment

Tags: angular, docker, npm, webpack, dockerfile

I am using Angular 5 and Node.js.

I don't know how on earth this would happen, but I notice my local environment is displaying different look than the one that I deployed via DockerCloud.

This is my

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 4202",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "3.2.16",
    "angular2-image-upload": "^1.0.0-rc.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
    "ngx-toastr": "8.0.0",
    "ngx-uploader": "4.2.1",
    "pace-js": "1.0.2",
    "popper.js": "1.13.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.0",
    "sticky-kit": "1.1.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

---

This is my

**web.dockerfile**

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:9.3.0-alpine as builder

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force

## Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build
RUN npm i
RUN mkdir /web
RUN cp -R ./node_modules ./web

WORKDIR /web

COPY . .

## Build the angular app in production mode and store the artifacts in dist folder
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --build-optimizer

### STAGE 2: Setup ###

FROM nginx:1.13.8-alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY --from=builder /web/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/

RUN touch /var/run/nginx.pid && \
  chown -R nginx:nginx /var/run/nginx.pid && \
  chown -R nginx:nginx /var/cache/nginx && \
  chown -R nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html

USER nginx
```

---

## Result

[image]

[image]

Is it because of some kind of version different of some packages?

Comment: I'd start by inspecting the elements that are different in the browser.  For example, your "Total Revenue" card appears to have a different font size.  Is the HTML/CSS different between these two?  If so, work backwards from there to figure out what could cause that.

Comment: Local. I ran ‘npm start’ to see my project

Comment: Prod. I ran ‘ng build —prod ... ‘ u think that u lead to that issue ?

Comment: have you found a solution for this? Having a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue and solved it by adding --extract-css=false to my build command

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem,

No matter what I tried I always got an older version of my angular app when deployed in a live server!

After digging I found that,
it was my chrome browser caching `javascript`/`css` files.

**Solution:**

- Try to load the application in `incognito` mode and see if it fixes the problem
- If it solves the issue, then delete "Cached images and files" [example](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)